# Is it allowed to shoot video while offering Qurbani?

Tags: eid-ul-adha

I was quite not sure when my sister is law asked this question. Though I have seen many videos on YouTube related to kurbani. Still am not sure, if it is allowed. That's why I am seeking your help. Kindly do let me if there is a hadith or Ayah or any fatwah against  it.

Answer (score 1):

In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful

“Is it allowed to shoot video while offering Qurbani?” As much as I made research, I didn’t find any related fatwa. In addition, as a logical rule, there cannot be an explicit verse regarding that, because there was not the devices like camera that … / consequently it seems to be permissible to shoot video while offering Qurbani. Of course perhaps there could be a problem in the case that some people watch it as a heart-breaking or harrowing event and make them a bad feeling … Otherwise apparently it can be permissible by itself. Wallah o A’lamo (And Allah knows best)

Answer (score -3):

No, we don't use any kind of electronic device which shoot video, photo snippets or audious of our shariat.

Yesterday I had bayan about kurbaani @ our Mosque. The Imam said that don't take any video's or photos while offering qurbani. And this information is from Deoband Madarsa in Delhi[India].

This all I knew.

Comment: Shorty I'll give you further Detail or Evidence

Comment: Dear brother please kindly quote a hadeedh or a fatwa related to it.